# revising sentence in a more meaningful way

Tags: gerunds, clauses, commas

I have written the following idea.

> In addition, ridge-line detection, *horizontality of ridge-lines and
>   azimuth constraints on corresponding segment pairs are imposed as
>   rules*.

But, I have said to revise the italic part. I am doubted what is the wrong. I guess verb is missing... so, if I write it as

> In addition, ridge-line detection, **testing of** horizontality of
>   ridge-lines and azimuth constraints on corresponding segment pairs are
>   imposed as rules.

then would it be meaningful? thanks. any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think adding "testing of" is not necessary. What make your near perfect sentence problematic, imho, is that it's unclear which word (or words) is the subject of your sentence. A ridge-line detection? If so, then you will need a comma before *are*, and *are* can't be used because *detection* is not plural. Or is the subject the horizontality and constraints? Or is it the two kinds of constraints? Make these clear, and you will have a good sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence does not have one clear meaning. I've counted several possible meanings, and it mostly comes down to your separation of clauses.

Whether or not you should use "testing" depends on whether your are referring to the testing process or its result, but also on which possible overall meaning you are trying to convey.

If you are saying that you there are three things that are imposed as rules -- ridge-line detection, horizontality, azimuth constraints -- then this could be fixed simply by addition of the [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/what-is-the-oxford-comma) (aka serial) comma (placed before the "and"):

> In addition, ridge-line detection, horizontality of ridge lines, and azimuth constraints on corresponding segment pairs are imposed as rules.

Another option is that you have a [nonrestrictive clause](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaClauses__Restrictive_and_Nonrest.htm):

> In addition, ridge-line detection, which means testing the horizontality of ridge lines, and azimuth constraints on corresponding segment pairs are imposed as rules.

Instead of commas, you could use [parentheses](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/parens.asp):

> In addition, ridge-line detection (testing horizontality of ridge lines) and azimuth constraints on corresponding segment pairs are imposed as rules.

You may even have improper count agreement:

> > In addition, ridge-line detection (testing horizontality of ridge lines and azimuth constraints on corresponding segment pairs) is imposed as a rule.

If one of these is not correct, then try to explain in your question what parts of your sentence are related to which others.

Comment: thanks,actually i am doing all 3 things.. so i missed the comma according to your comments. is so, any other way to improve this sentence. (other than just inserting a comma only).. anyway many thanks